# How to create transparent watermark on an image using gdlibrary?

Tags: php, gd

How to create transparent watermark on an image using `gd` library?

I want to rotate the image and tile it through out entire image also. Can anyone point me to tutorials, or provide solutions with examples please?

Comment: Why down vote this? Is something wrong with my question?

Comment: yes. This is not a place where people code for you. This is a place where people *help* you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/watermark-images-php

Comment: there is not a script to rotate the image, and it does not have script for transparent image

Comment: @Lo'oris, I thought this is the place where you help people with their coding.

Comment: @Starx: Very true. So, where is your coding, what part of it doesn't work, and how does it fail, exactly?

Comment: @Duroth, If I had a error I would post a error and then ask for you guys to solve, not ask how to. I am sorry if i offended you

Comment: @Starx: No offense taken, and I'm sorry my comment came across as rude. The point Lo'oris and me were making is that StackOverflow really isn't the place to ask code requests (I need so-and-so, please send me the required code), which is what your question looks like in it's current form.

Lo'oris gave you a great resource, which will do 80% of what you want. Foir the remaining functions, you can look at http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php. PHP's own documentation is usually extremely helpful, and for specific questions that remain, StackOverflow is the place to ask them ;)

Comment: The code there doesn't worked for me, the transparency is converted to white color.

Comment: @Lohoris I don't know whether this is a PHP bug  as mentioned in the solution, but it seems to be more generic and worked successfully: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9658077/61821